# preparing pandas dataframes for plotting with errorbars

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, ggplot2

I'm preparing a pandas dataframe for plotting in R's ggplot2 with errors bars, which requires calculating statistics of columns. The errorsbars require the min value (mean - standard dev) and
max value (mean + standard dev). I get these using groupby/agg:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

df = pandas.DataFrame({"id": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                       "exp": [10, 20, 30, 40],
                       "res1": [11, 22, 35, 42],
                       "res2": [9, 19, 32, 40],
                       "res3": [10.5, 20.8, 34, 48]})
# melt dataframe
m = pandas.melt(df, id_vars=["id", "exp"])
# get mean/std
summary = m.groupby("exp").agg([np.mean, np.std])
# add min and max under "value"
summary[("value", "min")] = summary[("value", "mean")] - summary[("value", "std")]
summary[("value", "max")] = summary[("value", "mean")] + summary[("value", "std")]
```

Then plot with R as follows:

```
# plot with R
p = ggplot2.ggplot(m) + \
    ggplot2.geom_point(aes_string(x="exp", y="value", colour="variable"), data=m)
    ggplot2.geom_errorbar(aes_string(x="exp", y="mean", ymin="min", ymax="max"), data=summary)
```

Is there a way to simplify the computation of the "min"/"max" columns, since it's such a common operation?  Is the creation of a separate dataframe ("summary" above) necessary, or is there an elegant way to put the same information into the original melted dataframe?

groupby returns a hierarchically indexed dataframe, so I had put "mean" and "std" under "value" seems too complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try performing the same operation without your numpy .agg functions, and using the built in .mean() and .std() functions in Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                   "exp": [10, 20, 30, 40],
                   "res1": [11, 22, 35, 42],
                   "res2": [9, 19, 32, 40],
                   "res3": [10.5, 20.8, 34, 48]})

m = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["id", "exp"])

mean = m.groupby("exp").mean()

errors = m.groupby("exp").std()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mean.plot(yerr=errors, kind='bar')
```

You should get the following result:
[image]

Comment: Is there an equivalent to ``mean.plot(yerr=errors, kind='bar')`` in ggplot?

Comment: Are you loading the dataframe using rpy2 or are you saving the dataframe to some other format before loading it into R?

Comment: Also, here is nice post on error plotting with ggplot2 - http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_errorbar.html